# Incorrect Results when calling a Python UDF in Redshift multiple times within a single column inside a select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, amazon-redshift, udf

I am encountering an issue in Redshift where calling a UDF more than once per column inside a select statement is returning the same result as the first call to that UDF.

**Bit of Background**

I have a very simple Python UDF that calculates an md5 hash. The reason for this function is to be able to handle UTF-16/UTF-8 conversion before doing the hash so it is consistent with SQL server. Now the syntax or logic inside the function does not seem to be the issue as we have tried creating even simpler functions that produce the same behavior.

**The Problem**

My function is named MD5_UTF16 and is called by doing MD5_UTF16(yourvalue), and returns a hash string / hexdigest of the value you pass into the argument.

In my query I need to be able to do this (postgresql syntax):

```
SELECT MD5_UTF16(column1) || MD5_UTF16(column2)|| MD5_UTF16(column3) AS concatenatedhash
FROM MyTable
```

i.e. I need to calculate each hash and concatenate them in a single column. If I calculated each of those hashes separately in their own columns, the function generates the correct hashes for those columns. However, in my example above I have called each function and concatenated the results with the results of the other calls. In this scenario what is happening is all the calls to the functions are returning the hash for the first call i.e. MD5_UTF16(column1).

To clarify a bit further using example hash values. Let's pretend these are the hashes for each of the columns above:

- **Column 1:** 275AB169CBEE4550F752C634B9335AE0
- **Column 2:** B2214041A94F50B027FE1DEEC4C8474C
- **Column 3:** 91050DAEFFEE20CDA2FC9914B6E4EBE9

My expected result for the concatenatedhash column would be a simple concatenation of the strings above (275AB169CBEE4550F752C634B9335AE0B2214041A94F50B027FE1DEEC4C8474C91050DAEFFEE20CDA2FC9914B6E4EBE9)

Instead, what I am getting is a concatenation of column 1's hash 3 times:
(275AB169CBEE4550F752C634B9335AE0275AB169CBEE4550F752C634B9335AE0275AB169CBEE4550F752C634B9335AE0)

In my SELECT statement if I had called the function on column 2 (instead of column 1) first, then it would be the hash for column 2 that is repeated.

Has anyone encountered this before?

**NOTE:** You can only replicate this behavior if you are selecting data out of a table. So doing a:

`SELECT MD5_UTF16('hard-coded value 1') || MD5_UTF16('hard-coded value 2')`

with no table source will not replicate this behavior.

**Work-arounds I am aware of**

I do know of a possible workaround but I still would have expected my method above to work, so this question is not about applying the following workaround, but more understanding why the above method is not working.
 - Workaround: Calculate each hash in a separate column first then concatenate them. This will have potential performance implications on our end among other things.

**EDIT 1**
Have found that the issue I've described only happens when there is a join in my query.. even if none of the column data from the joined table are being used in my UDF calls i.e.

SELECT ...concatenated hashes..
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ...

Removing the join seems to cause the hashes to be calculated correctly. Will attempt a workaround using this new knowledge. Not sure if it has anything to do with the execution plan running the UDF's differently when a join is involved - even though none of the column data from the joined table is being used for the UDF calls.

Comment: Why don't you use the built-in function for MD5 (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_MD5.html)?

Comment: @Guy - I mentioned this briefly above - the reason is mainly to be able to perform hash on UTF-16 data and compare it to hashes generated in SQL server which are UCS-2 encoded (a subset of UTF-16). Redshift stores data in UTF-8 encoding and so using the built-in MD5 hash function would be hashing a UTF-8 encoded varchar, which can produce different results to hashing a UTF-16 encoded varchar. My function takes a UTF-8 input (since the input comes from redshift), decodes and re-encodes it to UCS-2/UTF-16 (like SQL server), performs the hash, and then returns the hash string.